# When is the Law of Large Numbers not True?

Tags: probability, limits, solution-verification

I am trying to create a mathematical example where the Weak Law of Large Numbers (WLLN) does not apply.

**Part 1:** Here is the basic definition for the WLLN. Suppose we have $n$ observations from a random variable $X$ . Let's define $\overline{X_n}$ =  $\frac{1}{n} \sum_{{i=1}}^{n} x_i$ and $\mu$ as the true value of $\overline{X_n}$. **Let's also assume that** $X$ **has finite variance**:

Then the WLLN states that:

$$\lim_{{n \to \infty}} P\left( \left| \overline{X_n} - \mu \right| \geq \epsilon \right) = 0$$

**Part 2:** Using Chebyshev's Inequality (https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Chebyshev%27s_inequality), we can prove the WLLN.

Chebyshev's Inequality is for an individual point $x$. That is, Chebyshev's Inequality describes the probability of an individual point from a random variable subtracted by the mean of the random variable (assuming that the random variable has some fixed variance $\sigma$):

$$\text{Chebyshev's Inequality }: \quad \lim_{{n \to \infty}} P\left( \left| x - \mu \right| \geq k\sigma\right) \leq \frac{1}{k^2}$$

If we re-define $k \sigma = \epsilon$ and $k = \frac{k}{\sigma}$, then we can re-write Chebyshev's Inequality as:

$$\lim_{{n \to \infty}} P\left( \left| x - \mu \right| \geq \epsilon\right) \leq \frac{\sigma^2}{\epsilon}$$

From first principles, we can define the variance of $\overline{X_n}$:

$$Var(\overline{X_n}) = \frac{1}{N^2} \sum_{{i=1}}^{N} x_i = \frac{N \sigma^2}{N^2} = \frac{\sigma^2}{N}$$

We can now use this observation and update Chebyshev's Inequality:

$$\lim_{{n \to \infty}} P\left( \left| \overline{X_n} - \mu \right| \geq \epsilon \right) \leq \frac{Var(\overline{X_n})}{\epsilon^2} = \frac{\sigma^2}{N\epsilon^2} $$

Evaluating the limit, we see that:

$$\lim_{{n \to \infty}} \frac{\sigma^2}{N\epsilon^2} = 0$$

This means that as the number of observations used to calculate $\overline{X_n}$ becomes larger and larger, the probability of $\overline{X_n} = \mu$ also becomes larger and larger. This concludes the proof of the WLLN.

**Part 3:** Here is my logic: If I want to create an example where WLLN does not hold, then this case should "violate" Chebyshev's Inequality.

The example I thought of involves  $X$ having non-zero covariances. Specifically:

$$Var(\overline{X_n}) = Var(\frac{1}{N} \sum_{{i=1}}^{N} x_i) = \frac{1}{N^2} \sum_{{i=1}}^{N} \sum_{{j=1}}^{N} Cov(X_i, X_j) $$

$$ Cov(X_i, X_i) = Var(X_i) = \sigma^2 $$

Thus, suppose I define two random variables $X_1$ and $X_2$ such that $Cov(X_1, X_2) = c$. If I define $M = \frac{X_1 + X_2}{2}$, then I can evaluate the Variance of $M$ as (assume the true mean of $M$ is $\mu$):

$$Var(M) = Var\left(\frac{X_1 + X_2}{2}\right) = \frac{1}{4} \left[ Var(X_1) + Var(X_2) + 2Cov(X_1, X_2) \right] = \frac{1}{4} \left( 2\sigma^2 + 2c \right) = \frac{\sigma^2}{2} + \frac{c}{2} = \frac{\sigma^2 + c}{2}$$

Now, suppose there are $N$ random variables with each pairwise covariance $Cov(X_i, X_j) = c_{ij}$. Note that there will be $\frac{N(N-1)}{2}$ covariance terms.

We can redefine $M = \sum_{{i=1}}^{N} \frac{X_i}{N}$ and the variance of M as:

$$Var(M) = Var\left(\frac{X_1 + X_2 + ... + X_N}{N}\right) = \frac{1}{N^2} \left[ Var(X_1) + Var(X_2) + ... + Var(X_N) +  2Cov(X_1, X_2) +  Cov(X_1, X_3) + 2Cov(X_2, X_3) + .... \right] = \frac{1}{N^2} \left( N\sigma^2 +  \sum_{{i=1}}^{n} \sum_{{j \neq i, j=1}}^{n} Cov(X_i, X_j) \right)$$

We can apply this result within Chebyshev's Inequality:

$$\lim_{{n \to \infty}} P\left( \left| \overline{X_n} - \mu \right| \geq \epsilon \right) \leq \frac{\frac{1}{N^2} \left( N\sigma^2 +  \sum_{{i=1}}^{N} \sum_{{j \neq i, j=1}}^{N} Cov(X_i, X_j) \right)}{\epsilon^2} $$

And from here, it is uncertain whether:

$$\lim_{{N \to \infty}} \sum_{{i=1}}^{N} \sum_{{j \neq i, j=1}}^{N} \frac{Cov(X_i, X_j)}{N^2} = 0 $$

**Therefore, in the above case, the Weak Law of Large Numbers does not hold.**

**My Question:** Can someone please tell me if my analysis is correct? Have I correctly created an example where the Weak Law of Large Numbers does not hold?

Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

Yes, covariance can cause the WLLN to fail. It's usually best to analyze an extreme case, and the most extreme case is when all the random variables are identical. If $X_i= X$ for all $i$, then, $\overline X_n = X$ and we have $P( |\overline X_n-\mu|>\epsilon) = P(|X-\mu|>\epsilon),$ which doesn't depend on $n$, so doesn't tend to zero (unless it's zero, which only happens for all $\epsilon$ if $X$ is a constant random variable).

Comment: thank you so much for your answer! Do you think Central Limit Theorem will apply to the example I created?

Comment: @stats_noob You don't really have an example, or rather your example is too broad to say one way or the other. For different choices of distributions (and thus different $c_{i,j}$'s, we may have CLT or not have CLT (similarly WLLN). In the situation where all variables are the same, we have neither, and this behavior persists to nearby 'persistent correlation' cases, e.g. where the variables are all driven by a common factor.

Comment: @ spaceisdarkgreen: thank you for your reply! I will post a follow-up to this question

Comment: Please see this new question: https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4825422/creating-a-simulation-to-disprove-the-law-of-large-numbers thank you!